# Use pandas to make a list dataframe. Each row would be a list inside the original list with headers matching the value key in each list

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2, gspread

I am making a network switch config builder. Using gspread, jinja2, and pandas. I am not the greatest with structured data and I've spent hours on this.

```
parameter = worksheet.get_all_records() # using API to pulled down the data from google spreadsheet
df = pd.DataFrame(parameter) #convert to pandas
switch_data = df.to_dict('records') ## This is prob what I need assistance with
```

google sheet data below: top row will never change and is the column headers.

```
NewSwitchHostname   NewSwitchIP SubnetMask  Gateway
1234-SW-ER-01   10.0.0.7    255.255.255.0   10.0.0.6
1234-SW-ER-02   10.0.0.8    255.255.255.0   10.0.0.6
1234-SW-ER-03   10.0.0.9    255.255.255.0   10.0.0.6
```

switch_data:

```
[{'NewSwitchHostname': '1234-SW-ER-01', 'NewSwitchIP': '10.0.0.7', 'SubnetMask': '255.255.255.0', 'Gateway': '10.0.0.6'}, {'NewSwitchHostname': '1234-SW-ER-02', 'NewSwitchIP': '10.0.0.8', 'SubnetMask': '255.255.255.0', 'Gateway': '10.0.0.6'}, {'NewSwitchHostname': '1234-SW-ER-03', 'NewSwitchIP': '10.0.0.9', 'SubnetMask': '255.255.255.0', 'Gateway': '10.0.0.6'}]
```

I believe each row would need to be in a list. Essentially like the following

```
[{'NewSwitchHostname': '1234-SW-ER-01', 'NewSwitchIP': '10.0.0.7', 'SubnetMask': '255.255.255.0', 'Gateway': '10.0.0.6'}], [{'NewSwitchHostname': '1234-SW-ER-02', 'NewSwitchIP': '10.0.0.8', 'SubnetMask': '255.255.255.0', 'Gateway': '10.0.0.6'}], [{'NewSwitchHostname': '1234-SW-ER-03', 'NewSwitchIP': '10.0.0.9', 'SubnetMask': '255.255.255.0', 'Gateway': '10.0.0.6'}]
```

jinja2 loop:

```
for i in switch_data:
    result = template.render(i)
    f = open(os.path.join(home_folder, i[0] + ".txt"), "w")
    f.write(result)
    f.close()
```

Comment: `switch_data = [ [d] for d in df.to_dict("records") ]`. Not sure why you need a list with only one dictionary inside though.

Comment: Thank you! Worked as expected.